# Convergence of some improper integrals

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f\colon [a,+\infty[\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous bounded function such that $\int_{a}^{+\infty}f(x)\mathrm{d}x$ converges and let $n$ be any positive integer. 
Is it true that $\int_{a}^{+\infty}f^{n}(x)\mathrm{d}x$ necessarily converges as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is not true**. Consider $f\left(x\right)=\cos\left(x^{2}\right)$. It is clear that this function is continuous and bounded, and it is a well-known result that

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos\left(x^{2}\right){\rm d}x=\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{2}}$$

In particular, its integral converges (search Fresnel integral). However, it is easy to see that

$$f^{2}\left(x\right)=\cos^{2}\left(x^{2}\right)=\dfrac{\cos\left(2x^{2}\right)+1}{2}=\color{green}{\dfrac{\cos\left(2x^{2}\right)}{2}}+\color{red}{\dfrac{1}{2}}$$

By a simple change-of-variables the integral of the green part is convergent (to the value $\color{green}{\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{8}}$), and thus the integral of $f^{2}\left(x\right)$ diverges.